# numpyのunique()メソッドの挙動が分からない

Tags: python, numpy

numpyのunique()メソッドの挙動が全く分からず困っています。

```
import numpy as np
list_with_dupes = [1,5,6,2,5,6,8,3,8,3,3,7,9]
#(array([1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])重複が取り除かれたインデックス？を返す
print(np.unique(list_with_dupes, return_index=True))
array_with_dupes = np.array([[1,5,7,3,9,11,23],[2,4,6,8,2,8,4]])
print(np.unique(array_with_dupes))
```

2つの集合からunique()メソッドを使いprintすると答えとしてこのような値になるようです。

```
#array([ 0,  3,  7,  1,  2, 11,  6, 12], dtype=int64))
#[ 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 11 23]
```

array([ 0,  3,  7,  1,  2, 11,  6, 12], dtype=int64))の答えになる意味がわかないのですが教えていただけないでしょうか？

Comment: このコードを実行しても１つ目の`#array(...)`の結果は出てこないので他のコードがあると思うのですが、そちらも上げてもらえないでしょうか。

Comment: すいません。質問を修正しました。

Comment: `return_index=False`にすればおそらく所望の結果が得られると思いますよ。

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。完全に混乱していました。少し文章にするのが難しいのでとりあえずなぜそのような結果になるかはわかりました。

Answer (score 1):

`np.unique`で`return_index=True`とすると、uniqueな要素を持った行列と、入力として与えられた行列に対してのindexが返って来ます。下記のように、indexをはじめの行列に作用させるとunique_arrayと同じ要素が得られると思いますよ。

```
import numpy as np
list_with_dupes = [1,5,6,2,5,6,8,3,8,3,3,7,9]

unique_array, index_array = np.unique(list_with_dupes, return_index=True)

print('unique array : ', unique_array)
# unique array :  [1 2 3 5 6 7 8 9]
print('index array', index_array)
# index array [ 0  3  7  1  2 11  6 12]
print([list_with_dupes[idx] for idx in index_array])
# [1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Comment: pythonではじめるデータラングリングという書籍にもしっかりと書いてありました。「uniqueな要素（重複が削除された要素）で、　「その値がある最初のインデックスを返す。」私はpythonかじりのためリスト内包表記も一目みただけでは解釈に時間がかかってしまいます。

Comment: 愚痴みたいになってすいません。回答非常に感謝しております。

Comment: 確かにリスト内包表記な慣れるまでは読みにくいですからね。がんばってください。